# ScrollView и firebase storage?

Tags: java, android, firebase, scrollview, storage

Я создаю музыкальный проигрыватель и использую firebase.
Я хочу расположить на activity ScrollView, в который будет передаваться музыка из firebase storage. Как можно это сделать?
Я понял как работать с realtime database из той же самой firebase, но вот со storage и тем более с музыкой - не очень.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте список RecyclerView и заполняйте его из firebase.

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]